# What is the best way to let Google know the difference between a Production, Development, and Staging environment?

Tags: google-search-console, web-development, magento, google-chrome

We have three domain names with pretty close to duplicate content (they're Magento sites). We'll call them `production.com`, `development.com`, and `staging.com`.

I have robots `no-index` on `development.com` and `staging.com`. I also have *htpasswds* enabled. A Google search of these domains shows that they haven't been indexed. However, I'm starting to get phishing warnings from Chrome when I log in to the back end of the software.

I need to stop this as soon as possible. If the warnings spread to the front-end, we're looking at pretty serious ramifications.

I've looked in Google Webmaster Tools, but it isn't registering any issues.

What is the best coarse of action? How do I get Chrome to stop thinking we're up to no good?

Answer (score 1):

By `noindex` I assume you mean the meta robots element, and likely `robots.txt`, too.

Since you're using Apache you should try this directive:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive"
<FilesMatch "\.(doc|pdf|png|jpe?g|gif)$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This should suffice but banning all bots in `robots.txt` isn't a bad idea either (better safe than sorry).

Did you, or whoever would be the webmaster, verify ownership of all 3 domains in the same GWT account?